# Mapping Nested JSON Realm object in swift

Tags: swift, realm

I have is using Realm and Alamofire to get and store my data , but I got this one object which is a nested JSON object I am trying to access the Address but I get nil I am able to get the content data but not the address

"content": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "fisrtname": "Names",
                 "lastname": "last"
                "Address": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "city": "city",
                    "phone": null,
                    "street": "city",
                }

```
class Name: Object, Mappable {
@objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
@objc dynamic var fisrtname: String? = ""
@objc dynamic var lastname: String? = ""
@objc dynamic var Address: Address? = nil
override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
}

required convenience init?(map: Map) {
    self.init()
}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    id <- map["id"]
    fisrtname <- map["fisrtname"]
    lastname <- map["lastname"]
    Address <- map["Address"]
}

class Address: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var city: String? = ""
    @objc dynamic var phone: Int? = ""
    @objc dynamic var street: String? = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id <- map["id"]
        city <- map["city"]
        phone <- map["phone"]
        street <- map["street"]

    }
}
```

Comment: try to make `Address` class `Mappable `

Comment: no more copying -_-,  thank u for the help

Comment: @TarasChernyshenko I don't know how i ended up in the same situation as Nouf but I did, and you just saved me hours of head scratching. I guess it's easy to miss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to make model like this

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

    class Name: Object {
        dynamic var id = 0
        dynamic var fisrtname : String?
        dynamic var lastname : String?
        dynamic var Address : UserAddress? = UserAddress()

        override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
            return "id"
        }
    }


    class UserAddress: Object {

        dynamic var id = 0
        dynamic var city : String?
        dynamic var phone : String?
        dynamic var street : String?

        override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
            return "Id"
        }
    }
```

And To get address from Json :

```
let responseResult = result["Result"] as! NSDictionary
let name = Name(value: responseResult)
let address = name.Address?.city
```

Answer (score 0):

The comment left by [@TarasChernyshenko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203080/mapping-nested-json-realm-object-in-swift#comment93294376_53203080) solves the issue. If you're trying to set a relationship from a nested relationship, make sure you extend `Mappable`, forgetting this makes it very difficult to debug since you're not going to get any indication or hint about an obvious copy/paste/moving too fast/not enough coffee error.